# I am trying to create a binary search tree and do inorder traversal but it is not working.

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
```

my main class

```
class Solution{
```

Defined the node class

```
  class Node{
    int data;
    Node left,right;
    Node(int d){
        data = d;
        left=right=null;
    }
}
```

initialized root node here

```
Node root;
Solution(){
    root=null;
}
```

function for inserting a new node in the Binary search tree

```
void insert(int k){
    push(root,k);
Node push(Node root, int key){
```

if empty node encountered create a new node with the given key

```
    if(root==null){
        root=new Node(key);
        return root;
    }
    if(key>root.data){
        push(root.right,key);
    }
    if(key<root.data){
        push(root.left,key);
    }
    return root;
}

}
void Print(){
    inorder(root);
}
```

function for inorder traversal.

```
void inorder(Node root){
        if(root!=null){
        inorder(root.left);
        System.out.println(root.data);
        inorder(root.right);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    Solution sol = new Solution();
    sol.insert(50);
    sol.insert(60);
    sol.insert(10);
    sol.insert(80);
    sol.insert(20);
    sol.Print();

    }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having with it?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, I found the error just now, I was not assigning any value to root.right or root.left in the push function.